# Genymotion and AVD Emulator strange resolution on Windows 10

Tags: android

After installing Genymotion or AVD Emulator on Windows 10 they got a strange resolution (can´t post images due to my reputation).
I have already tried to custom devices and their resolutions. AVD Emulator has the worst resolution, even outside the device screen, where native android buttons are (on/off, keyboard...). Anyone else with this problem?

Comment: try updating your graphics driver

Comment: @KaranMer driver is up to date